# design inspiration collection of horizontal website layouts?

Tags: resource-recommendations, designers

Who knows a good resources to get some fresh design inspirations for horizontal layouts? Searching google gives some blogposts with relative bad quality designs.

I look for fresh, inspiring layouts but only ones that are horizontal.
This means non scrolling but a horizontal bar like:

http://www.planhq.com

Answer (score 2):

Site Inspire is a great resource for web design inspiration.

They even have a Horizontal category

http://siteinspire.com/showcase/category/style/horizontal_layout

Hope that helps.